# Jquery onBlur POST this.val()

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

How would one trigger a jQuery POST of the current input on blur.

`onblur="$.post(url,this.value)"`?

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) to bind the `blur` event handler to the `input`'s that you want, and then simply invoke [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) with the element's `value`:

```
$("input").blur(function () {
  $.post('url', { name: this.value });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send in an ajax post request to accomplish your task..

```
$("input").blur(function () {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'value' : $(this).val() },
        success : function(result){
        }
    });
});
```